# how to encrypt and decrypt with only public key with rsa c#

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, rsa, bouncycastle

I want to encrypt and decrypt the RSA using only the public key, but I get an error on the decryption side. Error: "unknown block type"
Can you help?

```
BigInteger rsaPubMod = new BigInteger(Base64.Decode("ALGZqqOFBDh6qULIV0hf5g+Zg5uQqTYWhrw9fzUJwWL8dW7V6kd+9kO8yD+1/f8NVmSDAWGfmVImsPNZp/8x/tF/DycPi5vfRuzHfFcT0mSgD7VW2CfuKM0Gh2WOpgXct6IMC7UsWTkPf8VBSgHobbkr+Ex5pm09mooe2KXTtXN3"));
BigInteger rsaPubExp = new BigInteger(Base64.Decode("AQAB"));
Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = new AsymmetricCipherKeyPair(new RsaKeyParameters(false, rsaPubMod, rsaPubExp), new RsaKeyParameters(true, rsaPubMod,rsaPubExp));
RsaKeyParameters pubParameters = new RsaKeyParameters(false, rsaPubMod, rsaPubExp);
IAsymmetricBlockCipher eng = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());
eng.Init(true, pubParameters);
byte[] encdata = Convert.FromBase64String("test");
var encdataResult = eng.ProcessBlock(encdata, 0, encdata.Length);
string result = Convert.ToBase64String(encdataResult);
IAsymmetricBlockCipher deng = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());
deng.Init(false, pubParameters);
byte[] decdata = Convert.FromBase64String(result);
var dencdataResult = deng.ProcessBlock(decdata, 0, decdata.Length);
string result2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dencdataResult);
```

Comment: If anyone who only had the public key was able to encrypt *and* decrypt, what would be the point?

Comment: It seems, that you should read something about how RSA works  :)

Comment: Perhaps what you need is symmetric encryption such as AES (Advanced Encryption Standard) which uses a single key for both encryption and decryption. Also note that Asymmetric data size is limited less then the key size.

Comment: Nobody can do this. You're needed to understand symmetric and asymmetric algotithm like AES, RSA.

Comment: After all, what I want is to encrypt and decrypt the data with a fixed public key. I have studied RSA encryption and decryption methods, but I have not found an example that only performs encryption and decryption with the public key. Do you have any information on the subject?

Answer (score 3):

RSA is an asymmetric algorithm.  With a public key you can encrypt, or perform signature verification.  With a private key you can decrypt, perform signature creation, or create a public key.